# How to enable x264 on Android linphone

Tags: android, voip, linphone

I am developing VOIP app for IOS/Android.

First time, I used H264 codec for video.

When I make video call, there is exist black video, as I see the log, there are many dropped packet so that first frame can not decode.

So I built IOS linphone library with x264 and it works well.

There is fast video after accept video call.

But still I can see the black screen on android because android used H264 yet.

I want to use x264 video codec on android linphone.

I used latest android linphone source code.

Here is my option.

```
./prepare.py -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=NO  -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_VPX=NO -DENABLE_VCARD=NO -DENABLE_DOC=NO -DENABLE_OPENH264=ON -DENABLE_X264=ON
```

Comment: Please let me know as well about x264.

Comment: Please check bellow link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647236/how-to-fix-black-screen-when-call-is-answered-and-loss-packs-on-h264/51468079#51468079