# How to fix black screen when call is answered and loss packs on H264

Tags: android, iphone, voip, linphone, openh264

I am developing VOIP app using linphone IOS/Android library.

Basically I used OpenH264 video codec.

When call is answered, both side saw black screen.

After long time, both size can see the video each other.

When I see the log, there are many packets loss so that First frame can not be decoded.

At LinphoneCallStreamsRunning, I called FIR (linphone_call_send_vfu_request) request but not helped.

Is there any config for OpenH264 video codec?

I want to see the video as soon as accept call.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done it? As getting same error here.

Comment: I solved that issue by using x264

Comment: Please let me know in details as I am using H264 codec in video and G722 in Audio. That would be very helpful for me.

Comment: But still getting black screen or you can add complete answer yourself here.

Comment: Do you want to solve the issue on IOS? or Android?

Comment: I am working on Android.

Comment: Basically Android linphone does not support x264, so I had to fix ffmpeg.cmake file to enable x264 on ffmpeg.

Comment: and I used latest library for ffmpeg,x264,openh264.

Comment: Here is configuration what I used.

Comment: ./prepare.py -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=NO  -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_VCARD=NO -DENABLE_DOC=NO -DENABLE_OPENH264=ON -DENABLE_X264=ON -DENABLE_EMBEDDED_OPENH264=ON -DENABLE_FFMPEG=ON -DENABLE_ILBC=NO -DENABLE_VPX=NO -DENABLE_MKV=NO -DENABLE_G729=NO -DENABLE_UNIT_TESTS=NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change ms2plugins.cmake file.

linphone-android/submodules/cmake-builder/builders/ms2plugins.cmake

```
lcb_build_method("dummy")

lcb_dependencies("ms2")

if(ENABLE_AMRNB OR ENABLE_AMRWB)
lcb_dependencies("msamr")
endif()
if(ENABLE_CODEC2)
    lcb_dependencies("mscodec2")
endif()
if(ENABLE_ISAC OR ENABLE_ILBC OR ENABLE_WEBRTC_AEC OR ENABLE_WEBRTC_AECM)
    lcb_dependencies("mswebrtc")
endif()
if(ENABLE_SILK)
    lcb_dependencies("mssilk")
endif()
if(ENABLE_OPENH264)
    lcb_dependencies("msopenh264")
endif()
if(ENABLE_WASAPI)
    lcb_dependencies("mswasapi")
endif()

lcb_dependencies("msx264")

if(ENABLE_VIDEO AND (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "WindowsPhone"))
    lcb_dependencies("mswp8vid")
endif()
if(ENABLE_VIDEO AND (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "WindowsStore"))
    lcb_dependencies("mswinrtvid")
endif()
```

2. Change ffmpeg.cmake file.

linphone-android/submodules/cmake-builder/builders/ffmpeg.cmake

```
if(LINPHONE_BUILDER_PREBUILT_URL)
    set(FFMPEG_FILENAME "ffmpeg-0.10.2-${LINPHONE_BUILDER_ARCHITECTURE}.zip")
    file(DOWNLOAD "${LINPHONE_BUILDER_PREBUILT_URL}/${FFMPEG_FILENAME}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FFMPEG_FILENAME}" STATUS FFMPEG_FILENAME_STATUS)
    list(GET FFMPEG_FILENAME_STATUS 0 FFMPEG_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)
    if(NOT FFMPEG_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)
        set(FFMPEG_PREBUILT 1)
    endif()
endif()

if(FFMPEG_PREBUILT)
    lcb_url("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FFMPEG_FILENAME}")
    lcb_build_method("prebuilt")
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "WindowsStore")
    # Use prebuilt library in the source tree for Windows 10
    lcb_external_source_paths("build/ffmpeg")
else()
    if(WIN32)
        set(EP_ffmpeg_PATCH_OPTIONS "--binary")
    endif()

    lcb_git_repository("git://git.linphone.org/ffmpeg.git")
    lcb_git_tag_latest("bc")
    lcb_git_tag("51aa587f7ddac63c831d73eb360e246765a2675f")
    lcb_external_source_paths("externals/ffmpeg")
    lcb_may_be_found_on_system(YES)
    lcb_ignore_warnings(YES)
    lcb_build_method("autotools")

    lcb_dependencies("x264")

    lcb_configure_options(
        "--disable-doc"
        "--disable-debug"
        "--enable-small"
        "--disable-zlib"
        "--disable-bzlib"
        "--disable-ffplay"
        "--disable-ffprobe"
        #"--disable-ffserver"
        "--disable-avdevice"
        "--disable-avfilter"
        "--disable-network"
        "--disable-avformat"
        "--disable-everything"
        "--enable-decoder=mjpeg"
        "--enable-encoder=mjpeg"
        # Disable video acceleration support for compatibility with older Mac OS X versions (vda, vaapi, vdpau).
        #"--disable-vda"
        "--disable-vaapi"
        "--disable-vdpau"
        "--ar=\$AR"
        "--cc=\$CC"
        "--nm=\$NM"
        "--extra-cflags=\$CFLAGS -w"
        "--extra-cxxflags=\$CXXFLAGS"
        "--extra-ldflags=\$LDFLAGS"
    )
    if(ENABLE_H263 OR IOS)
        lcb_configure_options(
            "--enable-decoder=h263"
            "--enable-encoder=h263"
        )
    endif()
    if(ENABLE_H263P OR IOS)
        lcb_configure_options("--enable-encoder=h263p")
    endif()
    if(ENABLE_MPEG4 OR IOS)
        lcb_configure_options(
            "--enable-decoder=mpeg4"
            "--enable-encoder=mpeg4"
        )
    endif()
    lcb_linking_type("--disable-static" "--enable-shared")
    set(FFMPEG_ARCH "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")

    if(WIN32)
        set(FFMPEG_TARGET_OS "mingw32")
        set(FFMPEG_ARCH "i386")
        lcb_extra_cflags("-include windows.h")
        lcb_extra_ldflags("-static-libgcc")
        lcb_configure_options("--enable-runtime-cpudetect")
    else()
        if(APPLE)
            set(FFMPEG_TARGET_OS "darwin")
            if(IOS)
                lcb_configure_options(
                    "--enable-decoder=h264"
                    "--disable-iconv"
                    "--disable-mmx"
                    "--enable-cross-compile"
                    "--cross-prefix=${SDK_BIN_PATH}/"
                    "--sysroot=${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}"
                )
                lcb_make_options("RANLIB=\"\$RANLIB\"")
                if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "aarch64")
                    set(FFMPEG_ARCH "arm64")
                else()
                    set(FFMPEG_ARCH "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
                endif()
                if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "armv7")
                    lcb_configure_options("--enable-neon" "--cpu=cortex-a8" "--disable-armv5te" "--enable-armv6" "--enable-armv6t2")
                endif()
            else()
                lcb_configure_options(
                    "--enable-runtime-cpudetect"
                    "--sysroot=${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}"
                )
            endif()
        elseif(ANDROID)
            get_filename_component(TOOLCHAIN_PATH "${CMAKE_LINKER}" DIRECTORY)

                set(X264_INC "$CFLAGS -I${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include")
                    set(X264_LIB "$LDFLAGS -L${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")



            lcb_configure_options(
                        "--enable-gpl"
                        "--enable-libx264"
                        "--enable-encoder=libx264"
                "--enable-decoder=h264"
                "--disable-iconv"
                "--disable-mmx"
                "--enable-cross-compile"
                #"--cross-prefix=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/"
                "--sysroot=${CMAKE_SYSROOT}"
            )
            set(FFMPEG_TARGET_OS "linux")
            set(FFMPEG_ARCH "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
            lcb_make_options("RANLIB=\"\$RANLIB\"")
            if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "armv7-a")
                lcb_configure_options("--enable-neon" "--cpu=cortex-a8" "--disable-armv5te" "--enable-armv6" "--enable-armv6t2")

            else()
                lcb_configure_options("--disable-mmx" "--disable-sse2" "--disable-ssse3" "--disable-asm")
            endif()

            if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "armv7-a")
                set(FFMPEG_CROSS_PREFIX "arm-linux-androideabi-")
            elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "aarch64")
                set(FFMPEG_CROSS_PREFIX "aarch64-linux-android-")
            else()
                set(FFMPEG_CROSS_PREFIX "i686-linux-android-")
            endif()

            if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET) # When building with clang
                lcb_configure_options("--extra-cflags=--target=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET} --gcc-toolchain=${_ANDROID_TOOL_C_COMPILER_EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN}")
                lcb_configure_options("--extra-ldflags=--target=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET} --gcc-toolchain=${_ANDROID_TOOL_C_COMPILER_EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN}")
            endif()
        else()
            set(FFMPEG_TARGET_OS "linux")
            lcb_configure_options("--enable-runtime-cpudetect")
        endif()
        lcb_configure_options("--cc=$CC")
    endif()

    lcb_cross_compilation_options(
        "--cross-prefix=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${FFMPEG_CROSS_PREFIX}"
        "--prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
        "--arch=${FFMPEG_ARCH}"
        "--target-os=${FFMPEG_TARGET_OS}"
            "--extra-cflags=${X264_INC}"
            "--extra-ldflags=${X264_LIB}"
    )

    if(ENABLE_X264)
        lcb_configure_options("--enable-decoder=h264")
    endif()
endif()
```

3. Change CMakeLists.txt file.

linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/ffmpeg/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(ffmpegandroid LANGUAGES C)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

#JamesChan
find_library(X246_LIBRARY x264)

find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)
find_library(SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY swresample)
find_library(SWSCALE_LIBRARY swscale)

add_library(ffmpeg-linphone SHARED)

#JamesChan
target_link_libraries(ffmpeg-linphone LINK_PRIVATE "m" "-Wl,-whole-archive" ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} ${SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY} ${SWSCALE_LIBRARY} ${X246_LIBRARY} "-Wl,-no-whole-archive")

#target_link_libraries(ffmpeg-linphone LINK_PRIVATE "m" "-Wl,-whole-archive" ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} ${SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY} ${SWSCALE_LIBRARY} "-Wl,-no-whole-archive")
set_target_properties(ffmpeg-linphone PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

install(TARGETS ffmpeg-linphone
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
)
```

4. Change x264.cmake file.

linphone-android/submodules/cmake-builder/builders/x264.cmake

```
lcb_git_repository("git://git.videolan.org/x264.git")
lcb_git_tag("adc99d17d8c1fbc164fae8319b40d7c45f30314e")
lcb_external_source_paths("externals/x264")
lcb_ignore_warnings(YES)

lcb_build_method("autotools")
lcb_cross_compilation_options(
    "--prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
    "--host=${LINPHONE_BUILDER_HOST}"
)
lcb_configure_options(
    "--extra-cflags=$CFLAGS"
    "--extra-ldflags=$LDFLAGS"
)
if(IOS)
    lcb_configure_options("--sysroot=${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}")
    string(REGEX MATCH "^(arm*|aarch64)" ARM_ARCH "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
    if(ARM_ARCH AND NOT ${XCODE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 7)
        lcb_configure_options("--extra-asflags=-fembed-bitcode")
    endif()
elseif(ANDROID)
    get_filename_component(TOOLCHAIN_PATH "${CMAKE_LINKER}" DIRECTORY)
    lcb_configure_options("--sysroot=${CMAKE_SYSROOT}")
    if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "armv7-a")
            set(X264_HOST "arm-linux")
            set(X264_CROSS_PREFIX "arm-linux-androideabi-")
            set(X264_USE_ASM "--disable-asm")   
        elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "aarch64")
            set(X264_HOST "aarch64-linux")
            set(X264_CROSS_PREFIX "aarch64-linux-android-")
            set(X264_USE_ASM "")
        else()
            set(X264_HOST "i686-linux")
            set(X264_CROSS_PREFIX "i686-linux-android-")
            set(X264_USE_ASM "")
        endif()

    lcb_cross_compilation_options(
        "--prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
        "--host=${X264_HOST}"
        "--cross-prefix=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${X264_CROSS_PREFIX}"
        "--enable-pic"
        ${X264_USE_ASM}
        #"--disable-cli"
        #"--disable-asm"
    )

    if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET) # When building with clang
        lcb_configure_options("--extra-cflags=--target=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET} --gcc-toolchain=${_ANDROID_TOOL_C_COMPILER_EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN}")
        lcb_configure_options("--extra-ldflags=--target=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET} --gcc-toolchain=${_ANDROID_TOOL_C_COMPILER_EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN}")
    endif()

    lcb_use_c_compiler_for_assembler(YES)
endif()

lcb_linking_type("--enable-static")
if(IOS)
    lcb_configure_env("CC=\"$CC -arch ${LINPHONE_BUILDER_OSX_ARCHITECTURES}\"")
else()
    lcb_configure_env("CC=$CC")
endif()
lcb_install_target("install-lib-shared")
```

5.Change ffmpeg-priv.h file if you used latest ffmpeg source code.

linphone-iphone/submodules/mediastreamer2/src/utils/ffmpeg-priv.h

Add following code.

```
#define HAVE_FUN_avcodec_encode_video2 1
#define HAVE_FUN_avcodec_get_context_defaults3 1
#define HAVE_FUN_avcodec_open2 1
```

6. Run prepare.py and make

   ./prepare.py -c && ./prepare.py -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=NO  -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_VCARD=NO -DENABLE_DOC=NO -DENABLE_OPENH264=ON -DENABLE_X264=ON -DENABLE_EMBEDDED_OPENH264=ON -DENABLE_FFMPEG=ON -DENABLE_ILBC=NO -DENABLE_VPX=NO -DENABLE_MKV=NO -DENABLE_G729=NO -DENABLE_UNIT_TESTS=NO && make liblinphone-android-sdk

IMPORTANT
This build will not work on x64, only work on armv7-a.

If there is exist any issue, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm using Linphone SDK (version 3.+). Samsung devices shows black screen during video call + can't hear any sound. If the other end of the call uses, any devices apart from Samsung, they can see him + hear sound while video call. any idea how to fix it ...